# Run function just before jQuery animation ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a scroller that animates scrolling using prev/next buttons. The duration of the animation is calculated based on the distance moved, so the duration is variable.

```
$c.animate({ scrollLeft: scrollLeft },
    duration, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {
        if (showPrev === 0) $s.attr("data-prev", showPrev);
        if (showNext === 0) $s.attr("data-next", showNext);
});
```

After the animation is done, I want to refresh the user interface (the buttons), which you can see is done by updating two data attributes.

To date, I've tried two different options:

**1. Update the data attributes before the animation**

I use a CSS transition delay to make updates happen later but cannot fully co-ordinate it with the variable duration of the animation - sometimes it can be way out.

**2. Update the data attributes after the animation**

I attach the update function directly after the animation, which works, but there is an obvious delay after the animation is finished before the updates kick in.

Neither is perfect.

Ideally what I would like to do is kick off the function just before the scroll animation is finished - so if the scroll duration is 1s I would like to update the attributes at `duration - 0.2s` (0.8s).

This seems entirely possible given that I have full control of the duration.

What I don't know is how to implement this using jQuery - possibly kick off two tasks in parallel?

I'm not a jQuery expert by any stretch of the imagination so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to calculate the duration of the animation. write a settimeout function with (animation_duration - 0.2s) and by this way you can trigger the kickoff function just before the animation function ends

Comment: Can you please provide an example given the code above

Comment: I have posted a example code, try to implement with that logic below in answer

Answer (score -1):

Please try with this code

```
$c.animate({ scrollLeft: scrollLeft },
duration, 'easeInOutExpo', function () {
    if (showPrev === 0) $s.attr("data-prev", showPrev);
    if (showNext === 0) $s.attr("data-next", showNext);

    time = setTimeout(function () {

    //keep your code here

   }, duration-0.2s);
});
```

duration-0.2s => make it correct, i just mentioned it as an example.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand. Tested and works great.

Comment: Sorry, I have tested again and the timeout does not kick in until after the animation has finished. So adds a further 0.8s to the original 1s.

Comment: cross check the duration with time-out function, were they triggering at the same time??

Comment: What seems to be happening with the code above is that the data attributes are still being applied  after the animation duration (1s). If I move the code inside the timeout it adds 0.8s to the animation duration, so 1.8 sec.